# different url for magento desktop site and mobile webapp

Tags: cordova, magento, jquery-mobile, web-applications, phonegap-build

I have my magento website [www.domain.com/](http://www.domain.com/) and recently developed a webapp at [www.domain.com/mobile/index.html](http://www.domain.com/mobile/index.html) both are hosted in my server.

i want to submit mobile sitemap to google webmaster as an alternative url when users visit my site from their mobile.

the issue is a product page of my Magento site is `domain.com/product1.html` and the url of the products in my webapp `domain.com/themes/shopper/product_detail.html?product_id=1`. the url of my webapp is defined by product id while the desktop site url is defined by url_key.
is there any way that i can create a similarity between the webapp url and desktop site url.

By the way the app was developed in `phonegap cordova` and i have uploaded the `assets/www` folder to my server using it as webapp

if any one can provide a idea it would be a great help

Comment: You might get more help with this at [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Web App and Mobile App are two different things. If you are using *cordova/phonegap*, your a building a mobile App. If you App is a wrapper for your website, It will be reject by Google and Apple Stores. READ THIS FAQ [When designing the app, thinks phonegap works like a website.](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005) -- especially the part from <i>Apple iTunes Guidelines</i>

Comment: I hired a developer to create a app connecting to my magento site for android and ios. A webapp version of the android app was also developed. thought to use it as a mobile website deeplinking the mobile website to google so that google can use it as alternative link for mobile users.